# Deadcode in Java

Tags: java, java-me

I solved the problem 3 in Project Euler about the Prime. I coded in java but I got error about dead code.
Here is the code:

```
public class Prime {
public int isPrime(int n){
    if (n==2)  
        return 1;
    else
    {
        for(int i = 2; i <= (int) Math.sqrt(n) ; i++)
        {
            if (n % i == 0)
            {
                return 0;
            }
            else return 1;
        }
    }
    return 1;
}
```

Who shows me why the reason is? Thanks!

Comment: How many iterations will you do in your for loop? Will you increase `i`?

Comment: What line is the dead code warning?

Comment: i++. Here is the dead code

Comment: It's because your loop will never iterate - once inside your `for loop`, it is guaranteed to return and never actually loop...

Answer (score 1):

You have a problem inside your for loop. To solve it, you should change your for loop to the following:

```
    for(int i = 2; i <= (int) Math.sqrt(n) ; i++)
    {
        if (n % i == 0)
        {
            return 0;
        }
    }
```

The reason for this is because the way you have constructed your for loop, it will only go through it once and only once. That is because `if (n % i != 0)` then you return `1` and the for loop terminates. What you want to do is wait until the loop has iterated through the entire sequence before returning 1.

The reason you are getting a warning under `i++` is because, as stated above, since the loop is only iterating once, it will never get to increment `i`.

PS: returning inside a method will break any loop it is in.

Answer (score 1):

You will never reach till ending return 1;

Loop will return on first iteration

This is simpler and working

```
class Prime {
    public int isPrime(int n) {
        for (int i = 2; i <= (int) Math.sqrt(n); i++) {
            if (n % i == 0) {
                return 0;
            }
        }
        return 1;
    }
}
```